# Not adding san after a name

Tags: meaning, usage

My manager when she talks about me to another coworker in the same company always uses my name without adding さん after it and this is only with me
can I know when we can drop using さん after a name?

Answer (score 3):

There are no simple/clear rules for when -san can be dropped, but in your case it should be simply because you are a foreigner and your manager is following the convention in English.

I suppose you are called by your first name alone while others (Japanese) are called family name-san. Most probably because it is very rare that Japanese people call each other by first names, calling **foreign** first names alone does not sound odd just as in English (i.e., it is understood as special cases).

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but actually, there are more foreigners at the company and she calls them and speak about them by their first name-san, so she's doing that only with me, and I was worried if this is out of disrespect or because I am from a developing country but others are not, can the age be the reason?

Comment: @JAM Then what I can think of is that you are younger.  Another thing is just the name (yours) itself.  Practically it is a personal taste, but for me, adding -san to longer names is cumbersome and I may choose to drop it.

Comment: Just to give an idea, at a workplace where I worked, one foreign person was called both with or without -san, depending on who calls him. So generally it is a bit random. If you are seriously uncomfortable, you need to talk to her, though.

Comment: Yes, I believe she's in her fifties while I am 24.
 At first, I didn't give much attention, but I noticed that this only happens when talking about me.
I don't have the gut to talk to her. so I preferred asking than guessing and feeling distressed about something that might be false But if she's doing that out of disrespect or racism it will sadden me. Thank you so much for answering me